# Let $a, b, n$ be integers and assume that $a, b$ are relatively prime. Show there is an integer $x$ such that $ax+b$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Tags: number-theory

I failed to prove this in one of the homeworks for Number Theory. I am wondering how to solve this. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Let $g$ be the GCD of $b$ and $n$; let $n=gm$; let $x$ be the product of all primes which are factors of $m$ but not of $g$.  (If there are no such primes, then $x=1$.)

See if you can prove that then $ax+b$ and $n$ are relatively prime.